# How to increment number inside string?

Tags: python, python-3.x, string

I have a string like so:

```
a = 'CODE1'
```

How do I increment the `1` inside the string by 1?

I tried this:

```
a = a+1
```

but got this errror:

```
TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "int") to str
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you tried a concatenation of `str` and `int` types. You have to select last character, convert to `int` for the increment operation and revert to `str` to concatenate with rest of string:

```
a[:-1] + str(int(a[-1]) + 1)
```

Or in cases discussed in comments, you can go for a regular expression to match last group of digits and perform the incrementation:

```
import re

a = 'CODE19'

splits = re.split(r'(\d+)', a)

print(''.join(splits[:-2]) + str(int(splits[-2]) + 1))
# CODE20
```

Comment: No, I didn't miss it. But I did miscalculate, it will work 19 times. Or maybe 18, I'm not trying to be exact.

Comment: @MarkRansom, you miscalculated again:) 19th result will be '110'

Answer (score 0):

You can increment last number in a string like this:

```
re.sub('\d+(?!.*\d)', lambda d: str(int(d[0]) + 1), a)
```